# Yellow screen error when attempting to login to Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Not sure who's end this is on, but I recenly tried to login to the Careers site to checkout the new bookcases and got a yellow screen error, relevent details are as follows:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid
>   URI: The URI is empty.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 31:  Line 32:            if
>   (filterContext.ActionParameters["returnUrl"]
>   != null) { Line 33:               var returnUri
>   = new Uri(filterContext.ActionParameters["returnUrl"].ToString());
>   Line 34:              var isAcceptableReturnUrl
>   = returnUri.IsAcceptedHost(); Line 35:                if (!isAcceptableReturnUrl) {
>
> Source File:
>   c:\builds\StackOverflowCareersAuth\prod\source\CareersAuth.Web\Helpers\AcceptedSiteAttribute.cs
>   Line: 33
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The
>   URI is empty.]
>   System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri,
>   Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>   +7955439    CareersAuth.Helpers.AcceptedSiteAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
>   filterContext) in
>   c:\builds\StackOverflowCareersAuth\prod\source\CareersAuth.Web\Helpers\AcceptedSiteAttribute.cs:33
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +72
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +709    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +162    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
>   +58    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   +20    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +453    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +371
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

This might have already been resolved as when I tried to login again things went through without any problems, although it took much longer than usual.

Comment: Yay! We can now see Source Codes of Stack Overflow.

Comment: *frantically copy/pastes before the revision gets nuked*  Piece by piece I will have the SO source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Rob, this should be resolved but let us know if you experience any issues.